# Populating textbox form ComboBox

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to populate a textbox form the selection of a Combobox element, However I get a Runtime 1004: Unable to get the Vlookup property of the WorksheetFunction class:

Code using as of now:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Change()
Dim GetRange As Range
    Set GetRange = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Report - Report").Range("I269:I287")
    Me.ClientComboBox.List = GetRange.Columns(2).Value
End Sub
Private Sub ClientComboBox_Change()
    Me.TimingTextBox1.Text = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Me.ClientComboBox.Value, GetRange, 2, False)
     On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Image attached of the data sheet = "Report - Report"

Thanks in advance :)

[image]

Comment: Within `ClientComboBox_Change`, you reference `GetRange` but you've not `Set` it.

Comment: `UserForm_Change()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three issues:

1. The scope of the variable GetRange is not global
2. You must control the type of the lookup value in VLOOKUP function
3. Use UserForm_Initialize() instead of UserForm_Change() unless you specifically require the userform to change.

   ````
   Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
       Me.TextBox1.Text = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CStr(Me.ComboBox1.Value), GetRange, 2, False) ' Control with CDbl(), CStr(), CInt()
   End Sub

   Private Sub UserForm_Initialize() 'Change this method
       Set GetRange = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:B3")
       Me.ComboBox1.List = GetRange.Columns(1).Value
   End Sub```
   ````